RegEx finding pattern in string ie 128x128
I have hundreds of thousands of files and easily 80% of them have a resolution in the file name, for example 128x128 or 270x360.
I'm renaming all these files based on meta data but want to preserve the resolution.  Example file names:

Grey Skyies 128x128.jpg
Rainbow Heaven 270x360.png
Happy Puppy 100x100 Blah Blah Blah.gif

I was hoping RegEx could help to find that pattern nnnxnnn so I can pull that out and store it (vb.net variable) to later rename the file preserving that resolution.

Use regex pattern: \d+x\d+ 
Which match 
   string pattern = @"\d+x\d+";
        
   MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

   foreach (Match match in matches) {
      Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
   }

Sample code
